# Email goes to first recipient only smtp mail python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I know, There are hundreds of questions with the same query. Sorry about this. I tried almost each of them. But still did not get the solution. In fact, I copied some of the code from one of stackoverflow query and improved it as per my requirement.

I'm writing a script to send error report using python for one of our server. My problem is `Email is sending to first member of RECIPIENTS only.` It needs to be send to the team of managers as well as to the admins at a time.

```
RECIPIENTS = ["mail1@gmail.com", 'mail2@mydomain.in' ]
TO = ", ".join(RECIPIENTS)
USER = "user30@gmail.com"
PASSWD = "userpass"

def sendmail():
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject()
    msg['From'] = USER
    msg['To'] = TO
    mime_text = MIMEText(get_msg_text(), 'plain')
    msg.attach(mime_text)

    #-- Auth by Gmail
    SERVER = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
    SERVER.starttls()

    try:
       SERVER.login(USER,PASSWD)
    except SMTPAuthenticationError, e:
        logit(e)
        return False

    try:    
        SERVER.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    except Exception, e:
        logit(e)
        return False
    finally:
        SERVER.quit()
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
   sendmail()
```

**Note** :- All the mentioned functions and modules are `import`ed properly. In fact, it sends mail successfully.

I tried following old posts:

- [How to send email to multiple recipints using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipints-using-python-smtplib)
- [SMTP sent mail to many recipients but doesn't received it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745171/smtp-sent-mail-to-many-recipients-but-doesnt-received-it)
- [Send Email to multiple recipients from .txt file with Python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941811/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-from-txt-file-with-python-smtplib)
- [Why can't I send emails to multiple recipients with this script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995445/why-cant-i-send-emails-to-multiple-recipients-with-this-script) and
- [many more](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=python%20smtp%20multiple%20recipients)

Comment: @all :- Please specify the reason before you do -1. If you can't specify the reason, you're not the right person to do that.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R - I tried that too, there was an error `list has no object lstrip()`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R:- Can you please link the documentation or syntax please?Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: edit: nevermind, for all those who stumble upon this thread, I found a solution here on the answer with the most votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib

Comment: other solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64947133/6007952

Answer (score 1):

To send the email to multiple people you need to pass a list not string in sendmail function. This will work fine for you.

```
try:    
    SERVER.sendmail(msg['From'], RECIPIENTS, msg.as_string())
except Exception, e:
    logit(e)
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the combinations on this post and the one recommended and using Python3 I couldn't make it work. This is the only way I manage to do it. It is not perfect as the ones reciving the emails are not geting all the emails where is being sent.

```
  for email in SMTP["to"]:
       msg = MIMEMultipart()
       msg['From'] = SMTP["user"]
       msg['To'] = email
       msg['Subject'] = f"[Repoman Notifier] Run on {today}!"
       msg.attach(MIMEText(html_builder(report_data), 'html'))

       server = smtplib.SMTP(f'{SMTP["host"]}:{SMTP["port"]}')
       server.starttls()
       server.login(msg['From'], SMTP["password"])

       server.send_message(msg, msg['From'], msg["to"])

       server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty old post, but just in-case some else runs to the same issue.
we had the same issue and the only way we could get it working was to use MIMEMultipart:

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

email_to = ['foo@here.com', 'bar@there.com', 'dumb@a.com']
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg['Subject'] = " You Tell me"
msg['From'] = "noReply@every.com"
msg['To'] = ", ".join(email_to)
#if reply_to:
#   msg['Reply-to'] = reply_to

part1 = MIMEText("WHY ME?!?!!", 'html')
msg.attach(part1)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.server.com')
s.sendmail("whyme@here.com", email_to, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

In your first *to* you have a `"`  but on the second email you used `'`; try to remove the `'` and replace with `"`